# How to show message instead of alert in javascript calculator as follows:

Tags: javascript

I want to calculate values of x and y from textbox values and the values 
should not be empty and not alphabetic. I have been able to do all these 
so far. However i do not want the result to be in a pop up. I want the 
result to be displayed as a text just under the buttons and it says 'Your 
result is.. '.

I have seen on the net that they use `document.getElementById` but I 
don't know how to use it.

```
<html>
    <form>
        1st Number : <input type="text" id="num1" /><br>
        2nd Number: <input type="text" id="num2" /><br><br>
        <button onclick="add(num1.value,num2.value)">Addition</button>

        <script>
            function add(x,y) {
                if(x.length == 0 || y.length == 0){
                    alert("Numbers cannot be blank");
                    return;
                }

                if(isNaN(x) || isNaN(y)){
                    alert("Value entered is not numeric");
                    return;
                }

                var result = parseInt(x) + parseInt(y);
                alert("Addition: " + result);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want the result to be displayed as a text just under the buttons and it 
says 'Your result is.. '

Please send me the codes if you are able to do it.

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702190/to-show-error-message-without-alert-box-in-java-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<body>
    <div>1st Number : <input type="text" id="num1" /></div>
    <div>2nd Number: <input type="text" id="num2" /></div>

    <button onclick="add()">Addition</button>
    <div id='result'></div> 

    <script>
        function add() {
            let x = document.getElementById('num1').value;
            let y = document.getElementById('num2').value;

            if(x.length == 0 || y.length == 0){
                alert("Numbers cannot be blank");
                document.getElementById('result').innerText = '';
                return;
            }
            else if(isNaN(x) || isNaN(y)){
                alert("Value entered is not numeric");
            }

            var result = Number(x) + Number(y);
            document.getElementById('result').innerText = "Your result is: " + result;
        }             
     </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Good. Did you apply this solution?

Comment: Yes i have applied the solution to my project. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a `div` element after your button:

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

And update it with the sum result by replacing your `alert` code:

```
var result = parseInt(x, 10) + parseInt(y, 10);
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Your result is ' + result;
```